# Select column header value for a column with the largest Sum - Matrix

Tags: python, dataframe, list, matrix, data-structures

I have a matrix for which I want to pick the value of the column header with the largest sum computed.

```
matrix= [['a','b','c'],                                                                
          [3, 7, 6],                                                                   
          [1, 3, 5],                                                                   
          [9, 4, 2]]
```

I compute the sum of this matrix as `[13, 14, 13]` for which I now want to pick the column header values i.e `b` with largest column sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transpose, sum and find the maximum column.

**Code:**

```
matrix = [['a', 'b', 'c'],
      [3, 7, 6],
      [1, 3, 5],
      [9, 4, 2]]

transposed_matrix = list(zip(*matrix[1:]))  
column_sums = [sum(col) for col in transposed_matrix]  # sum of columns
max_sum_index = column_sums.index(max(column_sums))
max_sum_column_header = matrix[0][max_sum_index]
print("Column header:", max_sum_column_header)
```

**Output:**

```
Column header: b
```

**Few lines of the same code:**

```
column_sums = [sum(col) for col in zip(*matrix[1:])]
max_sum_column_header = matrix[0][column_sums.index(max(column_sums))]
print("Column header:", max_sum_column_header)
```